# How to use fitdist function (fitdistrplus package) for binomial distribution in R?

Tags: r

When I try this :

```
x    <- data()  [,]
binom<-fitdist(x, "binom", method="mme")
```

this error occurs:

> Error in start.arg.default(obs, distname) : 
>     Unknown starting values for distribution binom.

Which method should I use and how to set all parameters to make it work?

I enter data from a .csv file. It looks like this, for example:

12.5
45.7
78.3
78.0
78.4
54.2
13.4
56.5
48.3
64.9
89.0
52.4
14.7
49.2
21.5
11.9
11.9
11.0
11.5
55.8
65.0
55.2
55.3

If I use "mle" method, another error occurs.

So, if I should set some parameters in fitdist function, just want to know what values to use.

Comment: Please include data to make this reproducible.

Comment: The package is fitdistrplus and the manual page indicates that the mme method requires additional parameters for the binomial distribution (because it is not one of the distributions listed that do not require the additional parameters). See ?fitdistr and ?mmedist. Or you can use the default mle method that does not require the additional parameters.